# __init__() missing argument: 'checkbutton' - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor

I'm having issues with my constructor. I get the error  ***__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checkbutton'***

**Update:**

this is my main file:

```
from GUI_Rootmodule import GUI_Root

gui_root = GUI_Root()
```

this is my rootmodule file:

```
from GUI_Unitmodule import Unit
from tkinter import *


class GUI_Root:
def __init__(self):
    print("hoi")
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Project: Embedded Systems")

    rootframe = Frame(window, width=1800, height=750)
    rootframe.pack()

    Unit(rootframe)

    window.mainloop()
```

this is my Unitmodule:

```
from tkinter import *


class Unit:
def __init__(self, master, checkbutton):
    self.frame1 = Frame(master)     #Frame voor labels, buttons, entries
    self.frame1.pack()

    # Checkbutton #
    print("test frame")
    self.var1 = IntVar()
    self.checkbutton = checkbutton(self.frame1, text="Automatisch", variable=self.var1, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, pady=20).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
    print("test checkbutton")

    # Labels #

    self.Extend_Label = Label(self.frame1, text="Uitrol afstand", pady=20).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
    self.Retract_Label = Label(self.frame1, text="Inrol afstand", pady=20).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
    self.Temperture_Label = Label(self.frame1, text="Temperatuur Trigger", pady=20).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
    self.LightIntensity_Label = Label(self.frame1, text="Lichtintensiteit Trigger", pady=20).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)
    print("test label")

    # Entry #

    self.Extend_Entry = Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
    self.Retract_Entry = Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
    self.Temperture_Entry = Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)
    self.LightIntensity_Entry = Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)
    print("test entry")
    # Buttons

    self.A = Button(self.frame1, text ="Inrollen", padx=10, pady=20).grid(row=6, column=0)
    self.B = Button(self.frame1, text ="Uitrollen", padx=10, pady=20).grid(row=6, column=1)
    print("test button")
```

I've tried to run in it, but it keeps saying that I'm missing an argument which i've put in **init(self, master, checkbutton)**

Can someone explain what I'm missing here and/or doing wrong ?

**Update 2:** Without the checkbutton code, the rest works and shows a simple GUI. It's still not clear where exactly i'm missing the argument for checkbutton

Comment: Well, the error is telling you that your Unit class is expecting that argument, but you are not actually supplying it when you instantiate the class (which you have not shown).

Comment: Please first fix your indentation, then post the full traceback and _all_ the relevant code (edit your post, dont just add it as comments).

Comment: This. We don't even know which instantiation is causing the problem.

Comment: I've just added the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't supply all of the required input parameters on this line:

```
 Unit(rootframe)
```

You supplied `master`, but are missing checkbutton. The class should be instantiated with all of the required input parameters:

```
Unit(master, checkbutton)
```

Alternatively, you can provide default values for the inputs and adjust the code in the function accordingly:

```
class Unit(master=None,checkbutton=None):
    ...
```

However, it looks like maybe you don't intend to pass in a checkbutton variable at all and meant to simply include a tkinter `Checkbutton`. If that's what you're after, I've included code for that below. I avoided the star import `from tkinter import *` so the source of the objects is more clear. I also combined things into the same module so the whole thing runs as-is.

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    gui_root = GUI_Root()

class GUI_Root:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hoi")
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Project: Embedded Systems")

        rootframe = tk.Frame(window, width=1800, height=750)
        rootframe.pack()

        Unit(rootframe)

        window.mainloop()

class Unit:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(master)     #Frame voor labels, buttons, entries
        self.frame1.pack()

        # Checkbutton #
        print("test frame")
        self.var1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame1, text="Automatisch", variable=self.var1, onvalue= 1, offvalue= 0, pady=20).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        print("test checkbutton")

        # Labels #

        self.Extend_Label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Uitrol afstand", pady=20).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        self.Retract_Label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Inrol afstand", pady=20).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        self.Temperture_Label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Temperatuur Trigger", pady=20).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        self.LightIntensity_Label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Lichtintensiteit Trigger", pady=20).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        print("test label")

        # Entry #

        self.Extend_Entry = tk.Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.Retract_Entry = tk.Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.Temperture_Entry = tk.Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.LightIntensity_Entry = tk.Entry(self.frame1).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        print("test entry")
        # Buttons

        self.A = tk.Button(self.frame1, text ="Inrollen", padx=10, pady=20).grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.B = tk.Button(self.frame1, text ="Uitrollen", padx=10, pady=20).grid(row=6, column=1)
        print("test button")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean here. I've tried to add parameters to Unit rootframe. But it's not working. What i don't understand is that my program works if i cut out the checkbutton but gives errors with the checkbutton

Comment: The way you've defined your class requires you to pass in a `checkbutton` parameter. You've only passed in `master` so far. Maybe something like `Unit(master=rootframe,checkbutton=my_checkbutton)` would be more explicit.

Comment: I updated the answer with code for including a checkbutton without having to pass it in. I think that might be what you're after.

Comment: I've figured it out. I had "checkbutton" in the constructor of unit where it should not be. And where I created the checkbutton I missed a capital C for Checkbutton (was checkbutton)